# Converting rtf to html with format in Java

Tags: java, html, rtf, jeditorpane, strikethrough

I can use JEditorPane to parse the rtf text and convert it to html.  But the html output is missing some format, namely the strike-through markups in this case.  As you can see in the output, underline text was correctly wrapped within <u> but there is no strike-through wrapper.  Any idea?

```
public void testRtfToHtml()
{
    JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
    pane.setContentType("text/rtf");

    StyledEditorKit kitRtf = (StyledEditorKit) pane.getEditorKitForContentType("text/rtf");

    try
    {
        kitRtf.read(
            new StringReader(
                "{\\rtf1\\ansi \\deflang1033\\deff0{\\fonttbl {\\f0\\froman \\fcharset0 \\fprq2 Times New Roman;}}{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;} {\\stylesheet{\\fs20 \\snext0 Normal;}} {\\plain \\fs26 \\strike\\fs26 This is supposed to be strike-through.}{\\plain \\fs26 \\fs26  } {\\plain \\fs26 \\ul\\fs26 Underline text here} {\\plain \\fs26 \\fs26 .{\\u698\\'20}}"),
            pane.getDocument(), 0);
        kitRtf = null;

        StyledEditorKit kitHtml =
            (StyledEditorKit) pane.getEditorKitForContentType("text/html");

        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        kitHtml.write(writer, pane.getDocument(), 0, pane.getDocument().getLength());
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      <!--
        p.Normal {
          RightIndent:0.0;
          FirstLineIndent:0.0;
          LeftIndent:0.0;
        }
      -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class=default>
              <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 13pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
This is supposed to be strike-through.
      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 13pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
       <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 13pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
<u>Underline text here</u>
      </span>
       <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 13pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
.?
      </span>

    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try converting with OpenOffice or LibreOffice using [this converter library](https://github.com/mirkonasato/jodconverter) as described [in this blog post](http://squallssck.github.io/blog/2013/02/25/about-how-to-convert-docx-slash-doc-slash-rtf-into-html-using-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I'm using to convert RTF to HTML from a .msg body.
See my Outlook message parser [**yamp**](https://github.com/gmax-ws/yamp) repository on GitHub.

```
public static String rtfToHtml(String rtfText) {
    if (rtfText != null) {
        rtfText = rtfText.replaceAll("\\{\\\\\\*\\\\[m]?htmltag[\\d]*(.*)}", "$1")
            .replaceAll("\\\\htmlrtf[1]?(.*)\\\\htmlrtf0", "")
            .replaceAll("\\\\htmlrtf[01]?", "")
            .replaceAll("\\\\htmlbase", "")
            .replaceAll("\\\\par", "\n")
            .replaceAll("\\\\tab", "\t")
            .replaceAll("\\\\line", "\n")
            .replaceAll("\\\\page", "\n\n")
            .replaceAll("\\\\sect", "\n\n")
            .replaceAll("\\\\emdash", "&#2014;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\endash", "&#2013;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\emspace", "&#2003;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\enspace", "&#2002;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\qmspace", "&#2005;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\bullet", "&#2022;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\lquote", "&#2018;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\rquote", "&#2019;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\ldblquote", "&#201C;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\rdblquote", "&#201D;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\row", "\n")
            .replaceAll("\\\\cell", "|")
            .replaceAll("\\\\nestcell", "|")
            .replaceAll("([^\\\\])\\{", "$1")
            .replaceAll("([^\\\\])}", "$1")
            .replaceAll("[\\\\](\\{)", "$1")
            .replaceAll("[\\\\](})", "$1")
            .replaceAll("\\\\u([0-9]{2,5})", "&#$1;")
            .replaceAll("\\\\'([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})", "&#x$1;")
            .replaceAll("\"cid:(.*)@.*\"", "\"$1\"");

        int index = rtfText.indexOf("<html");
        if (index != -1) {
            return rtfText.substring(index);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to some bugs, I modify your function like this :

```
public static String rtfToHtml(String rtfText) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    if (rtfText != null) {
        String[] lignes = rtfText.split("[\\r\\n]+");
        for (String ligne : lignes) {
            String tempLine = ligne
                .replaceAll("\\{\\\\\\*\\\\[m]?htmltag[\\d]*([^}]*)\\}", "$1")
                .replaceAll("\\\\htmlrtf0([^\\\\]*)\\\\htmlrtf", "$1")
                .replaceAll("\\\\htmlrtf \\{(.*)\\}\\\\htmlrtf0", "$1")
                .replaceAll("\\\\htmlrtf (.*)\\\\htmlrtf0", "")
                .replaceAll("\\\\htmlrtf[0]?", "")
                .replaceAll("\\\\field\\{\\\\\\*\\\\fldinst\\{[^}]*\\}\\}", "")
                .replaceAll("\\{\\\\fldrslt\\\\cf1\\\\ul([^}]*)\\}", "$1")
                .replaceAll("\\\\htmlbase", "")
                .replaceAll("\\\\par", "\n")
                .replaceAll("\\\\tab", "\t")
                .replaceAll("\\\\line", "\n")
                .replaceAll("\\\\page", "\n\n")
                .replaceAll("\\\\sect", "\n\n")
                .replaceAll("\\\\emdash", "&#2014;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\endash", "&#2013;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\emspace", "&#2003;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\enspace", "&#2002;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\qmspace", "&#2005;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\bullet", "&#2022;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\lquote", "&#2018;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\rquote", "&#2019;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\ldblquote", "&#201C;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\rdblquote", "&#201D;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\row", "\n")
                .replaceAll("\\\\cell", "|")
                .replaceAll("\\\\nestcell", "|")
                .replaceAll("([^\\\\])\\{", "$1")
                .replaceAll("([^\\\\])}", "$1")
                .replaceAll("[\\\\](\\{)", "$1")
                .replaceAll("[\\\\](})", "$1")
                .replaceAll("\\\\u([0-9]{2,5})", "&#$1;")
                .replaceAll("\\\\'([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})", "&#x$1;")
                .replaceAll("\"cid:(.*)@.*\"", "\"$1\"")
                .replaceAll(" {2,}", " ")
            ;
            
            if (!tempLine.replaceAll("\\s+", "").isEmpty()) {
                sb.append(tempLine).append("\r\n");
            }
        }
        
        rtfText = sb.toString();

        int index = rtfText.indexOf("<html");
        if (index != -1) {
            return rtfText.substring(index);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```